# active class javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used the following code to display menu

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="11"><a href="#1" class="cross-link cross-link1">Start a League</a><span></span></li>
    <li id="12"><a href="#2" class="cross-link cross-link1">Roster Settings</a><span></span></li>
    <li id="13"><a href="#3" class="cross-link cross-link1">Draft Settings</a><span></span></li>
    <li id="14"><a href="#4" class="cross-link cross-link1">Transaction Settings</a><span></span></li>
    <li id="15"><a href="#5" class="cross-link cross-link1">Playoff Settings</a><span></span></li>
    <li id="16"><a href="#6" class="cross-link cross-link1">Launch Your League!</a><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

If I click any menu the class `active` should be added in that particular li. How can i do it with javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

I supposed that you only wanted a single `<li>` with the `active` class.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j9qTE/1/